# Tagging results as text label in outer query with Multiple CTEs

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to tag the SumAmounts as Good project and Great Projects based on the question asked.

Here is the question and hints provided:
Exercise
Among successful projects, those that raised 100% to 150% of the minimum amount are good projects, whereas those that raised more than 150% are great projects. Show the number of projects (name the column Count) along with a string representing how good the project is (good projects or great projects). Name that column Tag.

The result should look similar to this:

Count Tag  
16           Good projects  
7            Great projects

Stuck? Here's a hint!
You will need two CTEs: one for those projects which raised 100-150% and another one for those which raised more than 150%. Use HAVING clauses to check the conditions. Use UNION ALL to show the results from both queries.

To create the Tag column use:

N'Good projects' AS Tag
and

N'Great projects' AS Tag
Mind the N – the column should be nvarchar type.

Here is where my code is at:

```
WITH GoodP AS(
SELECT d.ProjectId, p.MinimalAmount,SUM(d.Amount)AS SumAmount
FROM Donation d
JOIN Project p
ON p.Id = d.ProjectId
GROUP BY d.ProjectId, p.MinimalAmount
HAVING SUM(d.Amount)>= p.MinimalAmount AND SUM(d.Amount) <= p.MinimalAmount*1.5
),

GreatP AS(
SELECT d.ProjectId, p.MinimalAmount,SUM(d.Amount)AS SumAmount
FROM Donation d
JOIN Project p
ON p.Id = d.ProjectId
GROUP BY d.ProjectId, p.MinimalAmount
HAVING SUM(d.Amount)> p.MinimalAmount*1.5
)

SELECT COUNT(ProjectId) AS Count, CASE WHEN SumAmount IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE N'Good projects' END AS Tag
FROM GoodP
Group by SumAmount
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ProjectId) AS Count, CASE WHEN SumAmount IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE N'Great projects' END AS Tag
FROM GreatP
Group by SumAmount
```

My outer query is producing Good projects and Great projects but my counts are all single counts in the left column. The truth is I am not sure how to create the tags from SumAmount or if I should.

Comment: Not many people are going to do your homework for you. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I really shouldn't call it homework as I took it upon myself to learn SQL to help advance me in my job. I work on it when I can because SQL has helped me with some of the work I do at my job.

I had posted the question, the hint and the best code I could come up (what I had tried after several attempts) to answer the question.

With that being said, I just took the hint too literally and needed to do the following in the outer query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ProjectId) AS Count, N'Good projects' AS Tag
FROM GoodP
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ProjectId) AS Count, N'Great projects' AS Tag 
FROM GreatP;
```